# CakePHP change view for action in plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, view, path

I'm developing a plugin that has an action which decide the view to render according to data properties:

example:

```
class ProfilesController extends MyPluginAppController {

    public function myaction($id){
        //..omitting checks..
        $profile = $this->Profile->read(null,$id);

        //Stuff

        if($this->hasDedicatedViewFor($profile)){
             $this->render('profiles'.DS.$this->getDedicatedViewFor($profile));
        }

        //Else render default action view

    }

}
```

While this controller was inside the APP  everything was working right, 
after moving into Plugin, cake says:

```
Error: Confirm you have created the file:     
.../app/View/Plugin/MyPlugin/Profiles/myaction_secondary.ctp
```

While I'd expect to load it from:

```
.../plugins/MyPlugin/View/Profiles/myaction_secondary.ctp
```

Answer (score 0):

> While I'd expect to load it from:
>
> .../plugins/MyPlugin/View/Profiles/myaction_secondary.ctp

### It *is* attempting to load the default plugin path

If you trace through [the code for finding template files](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.3/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L1025-L1033) it is checking multiple paths for plugin view files:

```
    $paths = $this->_paths($plugin);
    $exts = $this->_getExtensions();
    foreach ($exts as $ext) {
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if (file_exists($path . $name . $ext)) {
                return $path . $name . $ext;
            }
        }
    }
```

The path in the error message is the last place CakePHP looks for a plugin view path, but it should also be checking the plugins directory. Debug the above code to see where CakePHP is looking for files if in doubt.

The path being wrong in the error message *probably* indicates using an out of date version of CakePHP; it's always, always a good idea to maintain your applications running the most recent maintenance release for the major version you are using. From the info provided that's [2.7.3](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/2.7.3) at the time of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll try to debug it. Maybe the path is printing is the first or the last one he tries